# How to compare a date from mySQL from the current date in java?

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am writing a simple log-in program in Java EE using the MVC pattern, and I wish to alert the user that his/her password is over a year old. Currently I can get the data from the database, and convert it into a string, but after that I don't know how to compare it to current date.

This is what I have so far:

```
public String validateAccount(String email, String enterPassword) {

        try {
            Class.forName(driverName).newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
                | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Connection connection;

        try {

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, username, password);

            // Retrive current user data from database
            String getCredentials = "SELECT id,dateSet,strength FROM users WHERE email=? AND hashPassword=SHA2(CONCAT(?, salt), 256)";
            PreparedStatement verifyCredentials = connection
                    .prepareStatement(getCredentials);
            verifyCredentials.setString(1, email);
            verifyCredentials.setString(2, enterPassword);
            ResultSet foundData = verifyCredentials.executeQuery();

            while (foundData.next()) {
                System.out.println("Found account");
                int id = foundData.getInt("id");
                String dateSet = foundData.getString("dateSet");
                String strength = foundData.getString("strength");

                // ... do something with these variables ... if
                if (strength.equals("Weak")) {
                    return "1";

                } else if (/*Check if the date in the database is over a year old, and return 2*/) {
                    return "2";
                } else {
                    return "0";
                }

            }
            foundData.close();

            return "Account not found, re-enter your info again";

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "";

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use foundData.getTimestamp() instead, and get a timestamp, which you can convert into a normal java Data class :)

So, you would have something like

```
Date dateSet = new Date(foundData.getTimestamp("dateSet").getTime());
```

or alternatively, if you are not familiar with working with Date instances (you'll need to use a Calendar as well) you can do the check directly in your SQL query,

```
String getCredentials = "SELECT id,dateSet,strength, IF(dateSet < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR, TRUE, FALSE) AS oldPasswd FROM users WHERE email=? AND hashPassword=SHA2(CONCAT(?, salt), 256)";
```

and then

```
else if (foundData.getBoolean("oldPasswd")) {
   return "2";
}
```

Comment: I am not familizarized with the .getTimestamp() method or with dates in general. What format would .getTimestamp return and how do I convert it?

Comment: Working under the assumption that the column in the database is a DATE type, then gettimestamp will return a instance of Timestamp, which then can give you a long which is the number of miliseconds since the unixepoc. The Date class has a constructor which takes a long representing the number of miliseconds since the unixepoc as a param, so thats thow you get the date instance :)

Comment: Good stuff, happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
java.sql.Date date  = foundData.getDate("dateSet");
java.sql.Date date2 =  new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
date2.compareTo(date);
```

I just modified the way you have accessed your date form the resultset.
Note that "compareTo" will return value 0 if the argument Date is equal to this Date; a value less than 0 if this Date is before the Date argument; and a value greater than 0 if this Date is after the Date argument.

Following method will get you the difference in days

```
public static long daysBetween(Date sd, Date ed) {
    Calendar startDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    startDate.setTime(sd);
    Calendar endDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    startDate.setTime(ed);
    Calendar date = (Calendar) startDate.clone();
    long daysBetween = 0;
    while (date.before(endDate)) {
        date.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        daysBetween++;
    }
    return daysBetween;
}
```

Comment: I understand that, but once I get both dates how do I check if there is a difference of 365 days (1 year) or more?

Comment: updated my answer with the method which will give you the difference in days

Comment: Thanks kunal, I will keep this as well.